# Scipy: Comparison of different kernel density estimation method?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

In python, there are several way of doing kernel density estimation, I want to know the diffenreces between them, and make a good choice.

They are:

1. scipy.stats.gaussian_kde, 
   http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html
2. sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity, http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity
3. statsmodel
   http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/nonparametric.html#kernel-density-estimation

I think we can compare with `1d, 2d`, `bandwidth selection`, `Implementation` and `performance`

I only have experience with `sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity`. Here is what I know:

The speed is generally fast, and can be performed over multi-dimention, but does not have helper in deciding the bandwidth.

I looked over `scipy.kde`, it seems like have a bandwidth selection method.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the article [Kernel Density Estimation in Python](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/01/kernel-density-estimation/) is precisely what you are looking for:

> I'm going to focus here on comparing the actual implementations of KDE currently available in Python. (...) four KDE implementations I'm aware of in the SciPy/Scikits stack:
>
> - In SciPy: gaussian_kde.
> - In Statsmodels: KDEUnivariate and KDEMultivariate.
> - In Scikit-learn: KernelDensity.
>
> Each has advantages and disadvantages, and each has its area of applicability.

[image]

Comment: Just a note - this is pretty old and uses Python 2 and old versions of sklearn/etc. However, a few web searches were able to fix that. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

The "sklearn way" of choosing model hyperparameters is grid-search, with cross-validation to choose the best values. Take a look at http://mark-kay.net/2013/12/24/kernel-density-estimation/ for an example of how to apply this to Kernel Density Estimation.

Comment: Thanks, this is very informative. It's not mentioned in the `sklearn` docs.

Comment: it's more of a general principle that applies to all types of models, not just Kernel Density, there's a bit more info in the page about grid serach http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html

Comment: Just tried it, `cv` is way slow for me. I got dataset with size about 50,000 point. It's 5-fold, (0.1,1,10). Is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: you can try setting `GridSearchCV(n_jobs=4)` (or however many cores you have) to run the search in parallel, this should speed things up, however grid and cross-validation are by their nature slow ... it's the price you pay for them having better statistical properties

Comment: also you could try reducing to 3-fold cross validation, normally this is enough

Comment: After tried it several times. I would say this approach is a good starter, but the value I get is too small in my case. Appears to be overfitting in for my dataset.

Comment: what do you mean too small? measured by what? by definition, the grid search will choose the hyperparamater which give the smallest (cross-validated) error, you cannont be overfitting since cross-validation uses separate train and test sets

Comment: Well, in my case, the `bandwidth` returned is `0.228` from `(0, 1)`, I tried some plot, it's simply too many `wiggles`. I compared it with `0.5`, `0.5` looks smoother, but not that oversmoothed like `1`. I think it maybe that the original dataset is biased and has some `wiggle`, i.e. observation error.

Comment: ok but this is an asethetic judgement you're making, it's not actally overfit although it may look like it is, the grid serach is minimising the *cross validated mean square error* -- this means that it trains a model on a randomly selected set of observations, tests it on a *separate* set that it's never seen before, and repeats this n times. this is statistically speaking going to give you better performance on future data than the simpler model that you prefer. (although you may prefer a simpler model for reasons of interpretability which is a valid reason)